# Error occurred loading a configuration file: Access to path c:\Program Files (x86)\... denied

Tags: c#, windows, file, config

I have an application which I deploy using a setup program in Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7. The program deploys and runs fine on Windows 7 and XP, but when I deploy it on a Windows 8 system I get errors about access to a configuration file.

The program gets installed in c:\Program Files (x86)[Company Name][App Name]\ and the file being referenced is a temp file with a name that looks machine generated by Windows GetTempFile, e.g. x4q0toqw.tmp. which does not exist in this folder and then there is a reference to the exe config file (myapp.exe.config, which does exist)

If I build and run the code on the Windows 8 system it installs and runs fine, I don't get the error, but then if I deploy the Window 8 compiled app on Windows 7 I get the same errors about access to the configuration file. Both machines are 64-bit but generate a 32-bit application.

I don't plan on releasing two binaries. Can anyone tell me what is going on? I'm in the process of trying to setup JIT debugging to that I can attach to the exe when it throws exceptions, since debugging it natively doesn't help me as I don't get the exceptions.

This is on two different machines, but I login to the same domain as the same user on both, and am an administrator.

Comment: Same machine? Admin rights in both sessions?

Comment: When do you get the errors, during setup or when the application is run?  Is the setup program one you've written yourself, or a commercial product?

Comment: I get the first error when the application loads, in the form_load call, which is where I load up all the configuration settings for the application. With that not functioning, nothing works. The setup is very simple, I wrote it, and it consists of nothing but placing the app in the program files folder, a shortcut on the desktop, etc.

Comment: @Gary: Did you find any solution to it, please share you work around to this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe your application is rewriting your app config during the load and this will cause the system to question the access grants... if so, may be you can change the properties of your application (the installed one) to have administrator rights... This will give your application to automatically have the right to programatically edit the app config.

OR... you can just forget about the app config rewriting and put everything in the default app config script. but this will expose your application database security...

Comment: Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts. Read  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. This is because the temp file gets created in `C:\Program Files (x86)\[Company Name]\[App Name]` folder and the normal Users (PC Name\Users) don't have the permission to modify this folder. As soon as I added modify permission, it started working fine.

Comment: You shouldn't grant modify permissions inside the Program Files folders.  Put the file in an appropriate location, e.g., ProgramData or (better still) the user's application data folder.

Comment: It works fine with following code after I set current app domain's config file location to the location of app.config kept in 'AppDataFolder'.

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\app.config");

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a very similar problem in Visual Studio 2010 on Win 7 by elevating the account privileges that my service ran under. See step 9 [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Adding%20Installers%20to%20the%20Service):

> Set the `Account` property to `LocalSystem.`

When my `serviceProcessInstaller1` ran under `LocalService` account I got an error like yours. But changing the account to `LocalSystem` fixed this issue. My installed service was then able to write to its `C:\Program Files (x86)\[Company Name]\[App Name]\[App Name].exe.Config` file. This was even though the install for `Just me` checkbox was checked when I ran the service's setup program.

Bear in mind the remarks [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceaccount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Remarks) though:

> The `LocalSystem` value defines a highly privileged account, but most
>   services do not require such an elevated privilege level.

Comment: Yes, so that's a very bad solution. The issue is that you shouldn't be writing to files in the Program Files directory in the first place. Installing your service to run as a user with administrative privileges to bypass that security is bad advice.

Comment: Hmm, well the service is only writing to its own config file.

Comment: Yes, that's what you intend it to do. It is a service though, probably with some kind of IPC mechanism, which through a bug might be used to access files in arbitrary locations on the machine, and access many other things regular users shouldn't, through administrative privileges. There's no need to introduce such an attack interface when you can simply store the config file in the AppData folder of the user running your service.

Comment: Ok, thanks - I'll bear that AppData folder option in mind. However my solution worked for me, even though it may not be the best solution, and the official [walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx) example used the `LocalSystem` account itself too! I did at least add a warning so I leave it up to the reader to decide what approach is best for them...