# c# App config settings windows 8 - access to tmp file denied

Tags: c#, settings, configurationmanager

This question was originally posted as "Error occurred loading a configuration file: Access to path c:\Program Files (x86)\… denied", but I didn't have much success finding a solution.

My application was written on Windows 7, it's a 32-bit application written with Visual Studio 2010. When I try to deploy this application on a Windows 8 system, the app fails during form_Load, with an error about access to a tmp file in the EXE's directory. I am not creating this temp file directly, but it has a name which is consistent with one generated by the C# GetTempFileName method. The name of the EXE config file (MyApp.exe.config) is also referenced in the error message.

I use the ConfigurationManager to store all of my application settings at startup, so I'm guessing that it is somehow related to this. If I build the application on a Windows 8 system it runs fine on the Windows 8 system, but generates the same error if deployed on a Windows 7 system. I don't know yet exactly what line of code is causing the error but the calls boil down to

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config =
            ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(settingName, settingValue);

config.Save();

ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Both the Windows 7 and 8 systems are 64-bit but the application is 32-bit. Thanks in advance for any advice in solving this.

I use the Settings class to handle the configuration data and the TEMP variable is what I expect it to be, my user\AppSettings\Local\Temp.

Comment: If you are not getting answers to your question it means your question is not clear.  Update your original question, this is a duplicate of that question, its not cool to duplicate questions.  As for not creating the file in a temp file you actually are.  You do understand you don't have to handle the configuration file yourself there is a Settings class that will handle it for you?  My guess your having a permission problem on both systems, handle that problem, and its solved on both.

Comment: A temp file should *never* be created in c:\program files.  You'll need to find out what's wrong with the config of that machine.  Focus on the value of the TEMP environment variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error occurred loading a configuration file: Access to path c:\Program Files (x86)\... denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344921/error-occurred-loading-a-configuration-file-access-to-path-c-program-files-x8)

Answer (score 2):

The problems encountered were on an evaluation version of Windows 8, this was all that was available. Running the application on a licensed version of Windows 8 Pro it works perfectly.

Thanks for the replies.